# remove the duplicate tr based on class (only if consecutive tr have the same class)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

There are two `tr` with the same class `"redline"` one after the other (that appears consecutively), I want to remove one 'tr' in that.

This is the HTML example

```html
<table id="test"> 
<tr class="redline"><td>bla</td></tr> 
<tr class="redline"><td>bla</td></tr>

<tr class="blueline"><td>bla</td></tr>
<tr class="redline"><td>bla</td></tr>
<tr class="blueline"><td>bla</td></tr>

<tr class="redline"><td>bla</td></tr>
<tr class="redline"><td>bla</td></tr>

<tr class="blueline"><td>bla</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: below is the example: <-table id="test">
1 <tr class="redline"=1><td>bla</td></tr>           
2 <tr class="redline"=1><td>bla</td></tr>       
3 <tr class="blueline"=1><td>bla</td></tr>       
4 <tr class="redline"=1><td>bla</td></tr>       
5 <tr class="blueline"=1><td>bla</td></tr>       
6 <tr class="redline"=1><td>bla</td></tr>       
7 <tr class="redline"=1><td>bla</td></tr>       
8 <tr class="blueline"=1><td>bla</td></tr>       
//<-/table>

Comment: Please put the HTML example inside your question, and format them in code blocks using \`\`\`html  your-code-here   \`\`\`

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do here `class="redline"=1` but that is not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `+` selector in CSS.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Here is the example:

```js
const dups = document.querySelectorAll('.redline + .redline')
dups.forEach((dup) => {dup.remove()})
```

```html
<table id="test">
  <tr class="redline">
    <td>bla</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="redline">
    <td>bla dulplicate</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="blueline">
    <td>bla</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="redline">
    <td>bla</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="blueline">
    <td>bla</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="redline">
    <td>bla</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="redline">
    <td>bla dulplicate</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="blueline">
    <td>bla</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelectorAll("#test .redline").forEach(function(element){
    if(document.querySelectorAll("#test .redline").length > 1)
        element.remove()
});
```

```html
<table id="test">
  <tr class="redline"=1><td>bla</td></tr>
  <tr class="redline"=1><td>bla</td></tr>
  <tr class="blueline"=1><td>bla</td></tr>
  <tr class="redline"=1><td>bla</td></tr>
  <tr class="blueline"=1><td>bla</td></tr>
  <tr class="redline"=1><td>bla</td></tr>
  <tr class="redline"=1><td>bla</td></tr>
  <tr class="blueline"=1><td>bla</td></tr>
</table>
```